# why is selecting a pk column faster than a non-indexed column?

Tags: performance, oracle

I'm currently doing some tests and I noticed the following:

```
select field1 from table1
```

Will result into an `index fast full scan` when `field1` is the primary key, thus with a low cost (in my case it is **4690**), whereas

```
select field2 from table1
```

Will result into a `table access full` (there's no constraint nor index on `field2`, *yet even with a regular index the result is the same*), with a cost of **117591**.

I'm aware of the gain when the indexes/constraints are involved in JOIN/WHERE clauses, but in my case there's nothing filtered: I don't understand why the PK should be faster because, *anyway*, I am retrieving *all* the rows...

Is it because of the uniqueness? Tom says that a [unique index is the same as a conventional index, structurally](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:7641143144618), which really makes me wonder why selecting the PK would cost less than any other column.

Thanks for your enlightenments :-)

rgds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A single-column b-tree index does not store data for rows that are NULL.  So if you have an index on `field2` but `field2` allows `NULL`, Oracle can't do a scan on the index without risking potentially returning incorrect data.  A full table scan is, therefore, the only valid way for Oracle to retrieve the data for the `field2` column for every row in `table1`.  If you add a `NOT NULL` constraint to `field2`, Oracle should be able to at least consider doing a full scan of the index.

Of course, whether or not the optimizer chooses to use the index (and the cost it ultimately assigns to using the index) will depend on the statistics that you've gathered both on the index and on the table.  If your statistics are inaccurate, the optimizer's cost estimates are going to be inaccurate and so the plan that is generated is likely to be inefficient.  That's one of the reasons that people are usually advised to be cautious about putting too much credence into Oracle's estimate of the cost of a plan-- if you're looking at a plan, it's likely because you suspect it is inefficient which should imply that you can't rely on the cost.  You're generally much better served looking at the cardinality estimates for each step and determining whether those make sense given your distribution of data.

Comment: i see, thanks. So you mean that any not-null column, not indexed, should give me the same good result as the PK select in the context of the simple selects I used in my examples?

Comment: @Sebas - If the column is delclared `NOT NULL` and there is an index on the column, you should get equivalent performance because Oracle can satisfy the query simply by reading the data from the index rather than needing to hit the table.

Comment: I'm still confused, since an index isn't loaded in memory or anything like this, how come returning all rows is faster if the rows are indexed or not? If we had to sort, do some joins... ok, but just retrieving the datas, brutally, how come it goes faster??

Comment: @Sebas - If Oracle can answer the query solely by reading the index, it is faster because the index is physically smaller than the table.  If Oracle can avoid reading any blocks from the table and can just read the smaller number of blocks from the index.  Generally, it's also slightly more likely that a particular index block is cached than that a particular table block is cached but that's a secondary factor-- the reduction in the number of blocks that need to be read is the primary factor.